# Passing python variable into the shell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bzip2

I have a folder, say `myFolder`, in which there are multiple csv files and I want to `bzip2` them. One option is of course to use shell:

```
bzip2 myFolder/file1.csv
```

How can I do it (same command) in jupyter notebook?

I tried:

```
for x in os.listdir("myFolder"):
    sourceFile = 'myFolder/'+x
    !bzip2 sourceFile
```

which returns

> bzip2: Can't open input file sourceFile: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for x in os.listdir("myFolder"):
    sourceFile = 'myFolder/'+x
    !bzip2 {sourceFile}
```

Passing Python variables into the shell–is possible using the {varname} syntax